# How to put an attr inside a custom drawable?

Tags: android, xml, styles, drawable, attr

I have an issue when trying to put an attr inside a custom drawable xml.

Here's a sample of my layout:

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/my_custom_btn"/>
```

Then my custom drawable "**my_custom_btn**", I want to specify its color with attr_my_custom_color:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="?attr/attr_my_custom_color" /> <!-- pressed -->
    </selector>
```

My attr.xml file:

```
<resources>
     <attr name="attr_my_custom_color" format="color"/>
</resources>
```

And my style.xml file, my application is using this theme (in my manifest):

```
<resources>
<style name="AppThemeTest" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="attr_my_custom_color">@color/primary</item>

</style>
```

My attr works fine when I test it in my layout, but when I put it inside my custom drawable, it doesn't work.

It compiles fine, but when I launch my app, it displays this error:

***Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #4:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable***

Can you help me to specify an attr inside a custom drawable?

Answer (score 0):

```
you have to change background to drawable


<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawable ="@drawable/my_custom_btn"/>
```

Comment: It doesn't crash anymore, but it doesn't apply `<item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="?attr/attr_my_custom_color" /> <!-- pressed -->` either.

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion ?

Comment: it also doesn't apply the color if I apply a standard color `<item android:drawable="@color/highlight" />`

Comment: please change thr minSdkVersion 21 then check. after that i will give you proper answer

Comment: I can only use minSdkVersion 19.
I can not check on 21. Does your proper answer implies to use minSdkVersion 21?